# Find all characters "[1-777])" at the beginning of the line

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl

Pseudocommand

```
perl -pe 'g/^[1-777])/g' data.txt
```

where I try to all numbers at the beginning of a line with ")" following them etc `1)`, `67)` and `777)`.

Data where all question numbers should (etc `1)`, `16)`, `68)` ... but not `16.` and not `778)`) be found

```
1) hello 
A) Options here which should be not matched. 
16) hello 16. old
A) Options here which should be not matched. 
68) yes question
A) Options here which should be not matched. 
...
582) hurray
A) Options here which should be not matched. 
778)
A) Options here which should be not matched.
```

where find only numbers until 777.

Wanted output

```
1,16,68,582,777
```

which I can then feed to my Sed command.
Lastly if possible, return the result as comma-separated for this command: `sed -n '1,4,582' full_data.txt`, discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/191678/15504), so some sort of piping from perl to sed or just in perl?

How can you return all numbers at the beginning of the line?

Comment: To me the question is incomprehesible. - Why get "1, 4, 582" for "1, 67, 582" ? - What are the input data, what are the selectors, and what are the exact expected results for the sample input selectors and sample data? - Please provide **consistent** data. - In what form are the selectors provided; hardcoded?

Comment: @Janis I want to find all characters which has `)` after them. The data is just a dummy example. There can be many other numbers too.

Comment: Is the 777 a limit, so `778)` should be ignored?  Also, why should `777)` not be found in the abovementioned example?  Please specify by editing your question.

Comment: @Ned64 Sorry my mistake. Fixed!

Comment: @Masi Did you want the numbers only, at the end?  Please give example overall output, then I can adjust my answer below to include this post-formatting.

Comment: [1-777] probably does not match what you expect. [] denotes character classes. A character class [1-777] is the same as the character class [1-7]. So, the regex ^[1-777]) matches any line which starts with one digit 1-7, followed by ')'. From the given examples, only 1) would match the regex provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some clarification iterations showed, only integer numbers and with values not larger than 777 shall be collected into a comma separated list. Here we go:

```
awk -F ')' '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && $1<=777 {print $1}' <datafile | paste -sd,
```

Note: To match an integer range you can in `awk` also write:

```
awk -F ')' '$1>=1 && $1<=777 {print $1}' <datafile | paste -sd,
```

I keep the variants below as building blocks for related tasks.

To create *all question numbers*:

```
cut -d ')' -f1 <datafile | paste -sd,
```

which creates this output:

```
1,2,3,...,582
```

Or, if entries with *empty answers* (like 777) shall not be considered:

```
awk -F ') ?' '$2!="" {print $1}' <datafile | paste -sd,
```

Or, if there's a *numerical limit* of 777 to consider:

```
awk -F ')' '$1<=777 {print $1}' <datafile | paste -sd,
```

Or to match only *integer numbers* in the first field:

```
awk -F ')' '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}' <datafile | paste -sd,
```

Comment: This command `cut -d ')' -f1 <data2.txt` returns also text after the number.

Comment: @Masi; It should not, and certainly does not in my tests. - Note `-d` specifies the delimiter, and `-f1` prints only the first field, i.e. the number before the delimiter.

Comment: All numbers are at the beginning of the line. So I think it is better to match cases at the beginning of lines with number `[1-777]` and `(`.

Comment: My Cut is BSD 2006, 21 December.  Yours?

Comment: I am using GNU `cut` but I'd expect the behaviour to be the same. - You may try replacing it with `awk`: `awk -F')' '{print $1}'`

Comment: Same thing occurs with the AWK, returning full line after the number. My AWK is also BSD. I installed GNU AWK. Same thing occurs also with it. Getting number followed by data.

Comment: Inspect carefully your files (have you used the correct data file?) and the commands you typed (have you typed it correctly?). Verify that the `)` in your data file is the same as the one you put on command line. Finally try calling `export LANG=C` and `export LC_ALL=C` before you issue the commands.

Comment: Note also that the behaviour of `cut` and `awk` is standard. If you have problems there's probably something in your environment severely broken. - In what shell are you working?

Comment: Sorry. I found the bug. I provided complete data to the body. Lines without numbers should not be included. Etc `ABC)` should not be matched.

Comment: @Masi; I added some more variants; the last to consider only numbers. Note that, depending on your actual requirements, you can combine the given conditions, e.g., use: `awk -F ')' '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && $1<=777 {print $1}'` (to allow only numeric data which are not larger than 777).

Comment: Your awk seems to work now! I am configurating the GNU paste to BSD here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/191670/15504

Comment: If you want to match all numbers at the beginning of lines, also those where missing `)`. Which of these would you use?

Comment: @Masi; the trick is that with a field separator defined as `)` you only have to compare the first field `$1` to be sure it's at the beginning. All solutions above consider the first field. - If you are now asking about line without `)` then you cannot use that field separator. You can match lines starting with digits like this: `/^[0-9]/`. But to match, extract and print them in `awk` you'll have to do, e.g.: `awk 'match($0,/^[0-9]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`.

Comment: This command `awk match($0,/^[0-9]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} <data.txt | paste -sd" " - > /tmp/1` gives me `code.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token \`('` and then the reference to the line. What did I forget here? Where are `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` declared? Can you, please, give an example what you mean by your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would first extract candidates, then check for the maximum 777 later:

```
egrep '^[0-7]?[0-9][0-9]?)' file | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\))/\1 )/' | awk '($1 < 778) {print $0}' | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\) ).*/\1,/' | tr --delete \\n | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

It works for my test files.  (EDIT1: The last sed now gives the number only EDIT 2: removed trailing `,`)

Comment: Your command also returns everything after the number. It should return only the numbers separated by commas like `1,2,3,...`. Sorry, I found the bug and provided complete data in the body.

Comment: I was not sure before. Changed that now!

Comment: I get this as an output `1) hello 
16) hello 16. old
68) yes question
582) hurray` before `tr` -part.

Comment: Are you sure you have used the `.*` part in the `sed`?  All text should be deleted (and is in my test data):  `echo '21) 34)'\\n'23)f' | egrep '^[0-7]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\))/\1 )/' | awk '($1 < 778) {print $0}' | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\) ).*/\1,/'  | tr --delete \\n` gives `21,23,`.

Comment: Yes, completely sure. I have BSD tools which likely cause the problem and I also use the actual test data in the body of question.

Comment: The problem *may* be due to the escaping of the special characters in the shell.  I use tcsh, and I tried bash, too (just needed to edit my echo  command in the test).  But this time it may be POSIX: Try adding a backslash `\ ` before `sed`'s `.` and/or `*` character - sometimes regexps vary a little here.

Comment: No need to add backslash, tested with and without. This `egrep '^[0-7]?[0-9][0-9]?)' data.txt | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\))/\1 )/' | awk '($1 < 778) {print $0}' | sed 's/^\([0-7]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\) ).*/\1,/'` gives `1) hello 
16) hello 16. old
68) yes question
582) hurray`.

Comment: @Masi On FreeBSD, please try `sed -E ...` or `sed -r ...` instead of just `sed ...` - does that work?  You could also try to install GNU sed for better compatability to the Linux version (If desired! Nothing against BSD!).